# i want to duplicate a signal generator output

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, generator, function-generator, dual

I want to duplicate signal generator output to dual. since i want to use same  signal to two different place. Is this possible without amplifying and inverting the signals. Let me share some circuit.

i just tried using two OP-AMP 741 and failed.

I have only basic knowledge in electronics.

Finally found working using below circuit...

[image: finally found working using this circuit]

Comment: what have you specifically tried, and how did that fail?

Comment: look into a voltage follower

Comment: i have tried an below circuit . it is not giving a output which i am giving in input. http://www.ni.com/cms/images/devzone/tut/vmbtsfev2596491556320455318.jpg

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it can be as simple as a splitter (putting the two sinks in parallel) or very complicated.   A 741 might be adequate for audio, but is in general a bad choice.  What kind of signal is it, and what are you doing with it?

Comment: That is a very simple circuit, and should work.

Comment: My signal might be a sine or square. i want to make dual output from single function generator. please suggest and share some circuit.

Comment: Please post the schematic in the question and not as a link in a comment where most people won't see it or won't bother.

Comment: "Failed" can mean a lot of things.  Did the 741 explode?  No output?  Low output?  Distorted output?  Too high output?  Oscillated?  The 741 ate your hamster?  What failed?

Comment: The circuit you linked to is an inverting amplifier.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. unity gain buffer is satisfied my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 2 unity gain buffer parallel for this. You may find details about unity gain buffer in google.

output of signal generator will be connected to the input of  each unity gain buffer input. output of each buffer will be same.

Comment: This should work, but only over a limited range of frequencies - particularly for 741s! Without more details of the expected usage, it is not possible to say more.

Comment: Thanks Koray. i got the circuit for unity gain buffer using UA741 and it is working. Now my need is fulfilled. https://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/unity-gain-follower-by-ic-lm741-1.jpg